# [OpenGL3.2]Error in glTexSubImage2D with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP as target and height and width are not same

Tags: opengl

I am using glTexSubImage2D with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP as target. It is giving me GL_INVALID_VALUE on my driver if height and width are not same . I am not sure of this type of driver behavior.As far as i know, it is not mentioned in glTexSubImage2D man page on Khronos.org.
Does anyone faced this?

Following are subsequent calls:
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,0,*internal_format,*width,*height,0,GL_BGRA,*type,color);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,0,*x_offset,*y_offset,*sub_width,*sub_height,GL_BGRA,*type,color+10);

```
where 
name="target" value="GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP"
 name="width" value="8"
 name="height" value="8"
 name="internal_format" value="GL_RG8_SNORM"
 name="x_offset" value="4"
 name="y_offset" value="4"
 name="sub_width" value="2"
 name="sub_height" value="4"
 name="type" value="GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8"
```

Comment: "*It is giving me GL_INVALID_VALUE on my driver if height and width are not same .*" You are not passing `width` and `height` to `glTexSubImage`; you're passing `sub_width` and `sub_height` to them. Are you certain which function is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected, the problem is that `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` is really just a simple form of array texture. When you upload a texture image to a cube map using `glTexSubImage2D (...)` you have to indicate which face (*effectively its array index*).

Valid faces (*targets*) for a cube map are:

- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X
- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y
- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z
- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X
- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y
- GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z

According to the OpenGL specification:

> Unlike a standard 1D, 2D, or 3D texture that have just one target,
>   a cube map texture has six targets, one for each of its six 2D texture
>   image cube faces.  All these targets must be consistent, complete,
>   and have equal width and height (ie, square dimensions).

However, in this case the problem is your target and not your dimensions. You can upload any sub-region of a texture image you want, this operation does not have to be square.

That said, in this situation it should be raising `GL_INVALID_ENUM` and not `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. Assuming you really are using `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`and not one of the 6 face enums listed above, then I am inclined to believe that this is a driver bug. I would need to see every one of the parameters you passed to `glTexSubImage2D (...)` and the call you used to create the image's data store initially to say for certain.

Comment: Note that the size isn't the problem; it's the broken target. `glTexSubImage2D` can upload rectangular pixel regions to cubemaps just fine. It's [the *storage* for the images](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage) that must be square.

Comment: Sorry i haven't clearly mentioned that i have used all the 6 target. Only difference is that i am not using square dimension. will that affect it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That actually does not fully explain why it is raising `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. I am starting to believe that part of the problem description is inaccurate.

Comment: @Neha: When you say you are not using square dimensions, do you mean in your call to `glTexSubImage2D (...)` or `glTexImage2D (...)`? Please include the call you used to create your texture faces initially in your question.

Comment: @Andon: Following are the subsequent calls.Please have a look in description

Comment: @Neha: You're dereferencing a lot of pointers in your code, can you include the actual types? The only reasons `glTexSubImage2D (...)` is _supposed_ to raise `GL_INVALID_VALUE` errors tend to have to do with negative values.

Comment: This issue got solved. It was driver bug. Thanks all for your quick responses